# Error while rendering PDF document through MigraDoc WPF on Azure Web Service

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, migradoc

While rendering document through MigraDoc with "pdfrenderer.RenderDocument();", have been getting the following error.
*
"System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)'"*

Can you let me know way forward since there is no specific library for PresentatioCore?

Answer (score 0):

The MigraDoc WPF package requires a Windows container and will not work in a Linux container.